# Add or Delete Columns Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add columns (or delete them if the number is reduced) between where "ID" and "Total" are based on the cell value in B1.

[image: Text]

How could this be done automatically every time the cell is updated?

Code I have so far

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B1")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To Range("B1").Value
            Columns("C:C").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the code you have tried and letting us know where it's not working will go along way for users to help you. SO isn't a code writing service. That said, `Worksheet_Change` event is what you need to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code:

1. Unqualified range references refer to a default sheet object.  While it won't be a problem *in this instance* (in a worksheet code behind module that object is sheet sheet containing the code, in any other module its the Activesheet), it's a bad habit to get into.  Use the keyword `Me` to refer to the sheet the code is in.
2. When changing the sheet in a `Worksheet_Change` event, use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent an event cascade (any time the code changes the sheet the event is called again)
3. Use an Error Handler to turn it back on (`Application.EnableEvents = True`)
4. Calculate how many columns to Insert or Delete based on existing columns
5. Range check the user input to ensure it's valid
6. Insert or delete in one block
7. On the assumption the "Totals" column contains a formula to sum the row (eg for 2 columns, row 4 it might be `=Sum($C4:$D4)`, when you insert columns at column `C` the formula won't include the new columns.  The code can update the formulas if required.
8. `Target` is already a range.  No need to get its address as a string, then turn it back into a range, use it directly

Your code, refactored:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim NumColumnsRequired As Long
    Dim NumExistingColumns As Long
    Dim NumToInsertOrDelete As Long
    Dim TotalsRange As Range

    On Error GoTo EH

    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("B1")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' Validate Entry
        If Not IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then Exit Sub
        NumColumnsRequired = KeyCells.Value
        If NumColumnsRequired <= 0 Or NumColumnsRequired > 16380 Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NumExistingColumns = Me.Cells(3, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3
        NumToInsertOrDelete = NumColumnsRequired - NumExistingColumns
        Select Case NumToInsertOrDelete
            Case Is < 0
                ' Delete columns
                Me.Columns(3).Resize(, -NumToInsertOrDelete).Delete
            Case Is > 0
                ' Insert columns
                Me.Columns(3).Resize(, NumToInsertOrDelete).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

                'Optional: update Total Formulas
                Set TotalsRange = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, Me.Cells(3, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).End(xlUp)
                If TotalsRange.Row > 3 Then
                    Set TotalsRange = Me.Range(TotalsRange, Me.Cells(4, TotalsRange.Column))
                    TotalsRange.Formula2R1C1 = "=Sum(RC3:RC" & TotalsRange.Column - 1 & ")"
                End If
            Case 0
                ' No Change
        End Select
    End If
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this code however I'm running into 2 issues. 1) When the new column is added, it isn't copy over from the column. 2) The sum formula that you recommended isn't working either. Any help on this?

Comment: 1) you are inserting,  not copying.   What do you expect to be copied?  2) _isn't working _ doesn't tell me much,

Comment: I get everything working and modified the code to allow me to copy the cell by adding "                Me.Columns(3).Copy
                Me.Columns(3).Resize(, NumToInsertOrDelete).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                Application.CutCopyMode = False". The problem that I'm now facing is that if I have a column of data such as "Comments" after the "Total" column that stops the entire formula from working. Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Comment: If you have more data to the right of Totals, then End(xlToLeft) won't work for you.   You'll need a different way to identify Totals column,  such as `Match("Total", Me.Rows(3), 0)`

Comment: Sorry for being a pain I'm still very new to VBA. Can you show where I would make that change?

Comment: Replace `NumExistingColumns = Me.Cells(3, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3` with `NumExistingColumns = Application.Match("Total", Me.Rows(3), 0) - 3`

Comment: Thank you so much for being helpful about this. If you are able to help me with one more step it would be greatly appreciated. Is there a way to make the Sum Formula only apply to specific rows such as, (rows 11 through 20, and then 25 through 28, and 30 to 31), instead of just all the rows after 3?

Comment: I can think of two ways, which one suits you will depend on your sheet layout. 1) Is there somthing distinct on the rows that require a Sum that can be used in a formula?  Something like `IF(RCx="Something", SUM( ... ), "")` where x is a column number. 2) If there is a pattern to the rows, code that pattern in VBA and only add the formulas to those rows

Answer (score 0):

may try the code below to have the result like 
[image]

code is more or less self explanatory

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range, ColNum As Long, TotalCol As Long, LeftFixedCol As Long
Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B1")
If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) = False Then Exit Sub
ColNum = KeyCells.Value
If ColNum <= 0 Then Exit Sub
Set Rng = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, Columns.Count))
Set c = Rng.Find("Total")     'the find is case senseticve, Change "Total" to desired key word to find
If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
TotalCol = c.Column
LeftFixedCol = 2          'Column A & B for Company and ID

Dim i As Integer
If TotalCol < LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Then ' Add column
        For i = TotalCol To LeftFixedCol + ColNum
        Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(3, i).Value = "Column " & i - LeftFixedCol ' may not use this line
        Next i
End If
If TotalCol > LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Then ' Add column
        For i = TotalCol - 1 To LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Step -1
            Columns(i).Delete
        Next i
End If
End Sub
```

However to keep the Sum formula on total Column consistence with added column, may limit number of minimum columns to 2 and inserting columns in between existing columns, by changing following

```
If ColNum <= 1 Then Exit Sub
```

and

```
Columns(i - 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

also delete line inserting column heading

```
Cells(3, i).Value = "Column " & i - LeftFixedCol ' may not use this line
```

otherwise may add VBA code to change `formula` of total column to requirement.

Comment: Set c = Rng.Find("Total") -> is a bit risky

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.
the named ranges are defined:

- "B1" -> "ColumnNumber"
- "B3" -> "Header.ID"
- "F3" -> "Header.Total" (but it changes as you add / remove columns)"

[image]

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim headerId As Range, headerTotal As Range, columnNumber As Range
Dim currentNumberOfColumns As Integer, targetNumberOfColumns As Integer
Dim columnsToAdd As Integer, columnsToRemove As Integer
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo error_catch

Application.EnableEvents = False

Set columnNumber = Me.Range("ColumnNumber")

If Not Application.Intersect(columnNumber, Target) Is Nothing Then

    Set headerId = Me.Range("Header.ID")
    Set headerTotal = Me.Range("Header.Total")

    targetNumberOfColumns = columnNumber.Value
    If targetNumberOfColumns <= 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    currentNumberOfColumns = headerTotal.Column - headerId.Column - 1
    Debug.Print "Currently there are " & currentNumberOfColumns & " columns"

    If currentNumberOfColumns = targetNumberOfColumns Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If targetNumberOfColumns > currentNumberOfColumns Then
            columnsToAdd = targetNumberOfColumns - currentNumberOfColumns
            Debug.Print "Need to add " & columnsToAdd & " columns"

            For i = 1 To columnsToAdd
                headerTotal.Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Select
                Selection.Copy
                headerTotal.EntireColumn.Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Next i

        Else
            columnsToRemove = -(targetNumberOfColumns - currentNumberOfColumns)
            Debug.Print "Need to remove " & columnsToRemove & " columns"

            For i = 1 To columnsToRemove
                headerTotal.Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Next i

        End If
    End If

End If

columnNumber.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

error_catch:
MsgBox Err.Description
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub